Can the Staging Ground be bypassed by using the Wizard?
I just ran across a question on Stack Overflow that seems like it should have been caught and improvement required in the Staging Ground before being posted to the site. Specifically Different spaces in the data section between C and C++
Checking the "Activity" it shows the question was created in the Wizard just 3 minutes before and doesn't appear to have gone through the staging ground process.
Is it possible for new-user questions to bypass staging simply by using the wizard to ask?

I'm pretty sure everything that does go into SG comes from the wizard (source needed. too lazy to dig up right now).

From Staging Ground Workflow: Question Lifecycle: "All posts in the Staging Ground, which at launch is limited to first questions, enter this status after they are created through the Ask Wizard." - I am not aware of the part about all SG questions coming from the Ask Wizard changing.

No, Stack Overflow do not (and refuse to) send 100% of eligible questions for the Staging Ground (SG) to the SG, but an unknown percentage is or there is a limit to how many questions are allowed in the SG.
As a result you will see users that aren't send to the SG when they really should be. This is, unfortunately, Stack Overflow's choice. I believe that they think this is due to the engagement level on the SG; they don't want to send more posts to it that won't be engaged with. Personally, I disagree with that stance, as I feel part of the reason engagement is low is because volume is low.
Also, the Wizard is used for all "new" users; the SG uses the Wizard as well. I can't remember what the exact criteria is getting the ability of opting out of the wizard; it might be the same as the SG, which is 500 reputation or 2 "successful" questions.
